# Dynamic grid display with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, grid

I'm trying to diplay some data got from server This data is dynamic, I'm using Javascript for it. I did this tas but with table, so I got a long list which is not conftable for the user experience.
[image]

I want to have the following grid display :
[image]

For diplaying dynamic table I'm using the following code. Can somoene show me how to change the code to have a grid diplay to have image and text under it, like in the second image.Thank you. :

```js
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

  var html = "<table border='1|1'>";


  for (var i = 0; i < obj.response.length; i++) {
          html+="<tr>";
          html+="<td>"+obj.response[i].id+"</td>";
          html+="<td>"+obj.response[i].restaurant_id+"</td>";
          html+="<td>"+obj.response[i].name+"</td>";

         html+="<td>"+'<img src="http://URL/' + obj.response[i].img + '" class="img-responsive" width="100" height="80"/>'+"</td>";

          html+="</tr>";

       }

   html+="</table>";
  $("#demo").html(html);
}

  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://URL", true);
  xhttp.send();

}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6"> <!--Div for displaying menye-->
    <h1>Display the menu</h1>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()" class="btn btn-primary">Menue</button>
         <table class="table table-striped" class="img-responsive">
                  <thead>
                      
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="demo"></tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: why jquery is tagged?

Comment: I deleted it, it was a mistake